# Formula for the general Cavalieri Sum: $S_n(p)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k^p\,\,\,n, p\in\mathbb N$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

What kind of formula is there that can be used for calculating the sum of power of $x$ of numbers from $1$ to $a$?

I know that the sum of numbers from $1$ to $a$ is $\ (n^2 + n)/ 2  \ $ and that the sum of the squared numbers from $1$  to $a$ is $n^3/3+n^2/2+n/6 $.

If possible, please give a solution that excludes Bernoulli numbers and works for negative numbers too.

Comment: Are you looking for $\sum_{k=1}^a x^k$ (as the title seems to suggest) or for $\sum_{k=1}^a k^x$ (as the first and second sentences seem to suggest)?

Comment: That correspond to the Cavalieri sums you better have to do it by induction.

Comment: I am looking for k^x. Someone changed the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$ S_n(p)=\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^p\qquad n, p\in\mathbb N ~~~~~\text{called Cavalieri sum of oder p}$$

then, 
We know the following Binomial formula

$$ (k+1)^p = k^p+ \sum_{i=0}^{p-1}\binom{p}{i} k^i$$
where $\binom{p}{i}= \frac{p!}{i!(p-i)!}$.
Which implies that,

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} (k+1)^p =\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^p+\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}\binom{p}{i} \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^i = S_n(p) +\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}\binom{p}{i} S_n(i) $$

But $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} (k+1)^p = \sum_{k=2}^{n+1} k^p = S_{n+1}(p) -1 = S_n(p) +(n+1)^p -1$$

Hence finally we get the formula :

$$\color{red}{(n+1)^p -1  =\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}\binom{p}{i} S_n(i)} $$

> From this it is possible to compute the sum for any $p\ge 1 $ in $ \mathbb N $.

Comment: What is (i on top of p)? Is it like a matrix?

Comment: It's a binomial coefficient. Do you know what $n!$ means for $n$?

Comment: But $i < p$, hence it's always 0. It should be $\binom{p}{i}$ instead.

Comment: I researched about the binomial coefficient. Thanks!

Comment: Ok Now rectified everything for you.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware of, there is no general formula.
There are several methods to compute these sums however, i'll mention my favorite one:

You find a polynomial $P$ of degree $n+1$, such that $P(x+1)-P(x)=x^n$. This basically means solving a system of linear equations and one can prove using elementary linear algebra, that such a polynomial always exists.
Once you have it, then you simply use telescopic sums: $\sum \limits_{k=0}^a k^n=\sum \limits_{k=0}^a (P(k+1)-P(k))=P(a+1)-P(0)$.

Comment: So, do you mean that if you find the formula/polynomial P such that P(x+1)-P(x)=x^n, I could compute the sum of powers by using the equation P(a+1)-P(0)?